# Online hierarchically-nested data structures generated by folder structure on local machine

Tags: javascript, json, web, hierarchical-data, directory-structure

I am a computer music student with more of a background in music than programming so please pardon my ignorance. I am trying to create a website whose online file structure resembles the local file structure of a directory on my disk. Most ideally, the website would reference a directory from google drive.

I am interested in programming in javascript because I want the data to be dynamically aligned with the web. At one point I had a wiki, specifically a PMWiki distribution. I am fascinated with nested data structures and love the json format for this reason. One of the things I disliked with Pmwiki is how I could not create nested directories on my local machine which immediately reflected onto the frontend of my website.  Seeking guidance on different approaches I might pursue. I am guessing I need some more knowledge in FTP or GIT for starters.

Comment: right now, what is the question of your contribution?

Comment: Is there a particular javascript framework which accommodates having a local file structure which immediately reflects onto the front end of a website? For instance, I want to create folders within folders and have the contents of those subfolders be recallable using json and dictionaries, but I also want to minimize the degree to which I need to actively re-upload my website from my local machine, with automatic synchronization preferably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that PHP is basically designed to do this, to generate website link structures based on folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Usually javascript is a scripting language that runs in the navigator itself. It does not really have access to your local machine.

If I were you I would create a File System Watcher using a machine language such as C++, C#, Java etc... that listens to any event that is triggered in the root & subfolders, and posts directly to your database.